# Python Selenium upload file to website by class name

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to use Python to upload files to a website. But when I looked at the Developer Inspection Tool, there is no id, and no name. I am trying to use class name, but it does not work.

Inspect window from Selenium:

[image: Screenshot 1]

Inspect window from website:

[image: Screenshot 2]

I've tried methods like these:

```
upload = driver.find_element_by_class_name("icomoon icon-upload2 toolbar-button fileinput-button")
upload = driver.find_element_by_class_name("fileupload")
upload = driver.find_element_by_class_name("btnContainer").
```

All failed.

```
the error message:
NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".btnContainer"}
  (Session info: chrome=91.0.4472.77)
```

Then I use:

```
upload = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('body > div.fileupload')
upload.send_keys(r'c\user\xxx\upload\excel.xlsx')
#or
upload = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='fileupload']")
upload.send_keys(r'c\user\xxx\upload\excel.xlsx')
```

The error message:

```
ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=91.0.4472.77)
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks,

JH.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a quick solution you can always try getting by ccs selctor. Right click on the element in the inspect widow. click on copy > selector. And then in python write `driver.find_element_by_css_selector('paste the selector here')`

This is not an elegant solution but it should work.

Comment: Thanks. However, I am trying to use upload.send_keys to upload the file, it failed.
here is error: "ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=91.0.4472.77)"